# Erro ao chamar um método em ASP.NET Web API e Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

Estou recebendo erro ao tentar chamar um método de um Web API.

Declaração do método na `ApiController`

```
public class AcessoController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public UsuarioModel ValidarUsuario(string login, string senha, string modoAutenticacao)
    {

    }

}
```

Consumindo a API

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlAPI"]);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("api/Acesso/ValidarUsuario?login={0}&senha={1}&modoAutenticacao={2}", model.Login, model.Senha, (model.ModoAutenticacao == LoginViewModel.Dominio.Computecnica) ? "interno" : "externo"));

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) //esta retornando falso
{

}
```

Erro:

> Cannot be null Nome do parâmetro: root

Parece ser falha na construção da URL, já que a execução desse método funcionou através de *UnitTest*.

Comment: Isto está bizarro. A API consome ela mesma?

Comment: Parece estar faltando o método na hora de consumir a API? Por exemplo: `client.GetAsync(string.Format("api/Acesso/ValidarUsuario?login={0}...` (incluí o "ValidarUsuario" no texto)

Comment: Estive olhando este exemplo e me parece que não e informado o nome do método. Parece que ele identifica qual metodo chamar, de acordo com os parametros passados. http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com.br/2016/09/aspnet-web-api-query-string-parameters.html

Comment: De qualquer forma, acabei de fazer um teste, colocando o nome do método, mas ainda não funcionou. Código esta atualizado na pergunta principal.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez não é a mesma aplicação. Tenho um projeto WEB API que valida os usuários, e uma aplicação MVC que consome esse Web API

Comment: Ele continua dando erro? Ou agora apenas retorna `false`? Investigando o objeto `response`, vc tem o código HTTP da resposta?

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro. 
Tentei chamar a url direto pelo browser:
 http://localhost:52337/api/Acesso/ValidarUsuario?login=cpt&senha=cpt&modoAutenticacao=externo

Erro:
Cannot be null
Nome do parâmetro: root

Comment: Ia dizer pra vc fazer isso mesmo. :(  Fiz uma busca em inglês e esse erro só aparece pra quem está usando Ninject. Você está usando Ninject?

Comment: Sim, esta com a mesma codificação do projeto MVC, pois ambos compartilham o mesmo projeto de acesso a dados, que esta codificado com injeção de dependencia.

Comment: Talvez a solução destes posts possa te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703903/wcf-with-ninject-throwing-argumentnullexception   ou   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451580/ninject-wcf-extension-argumentnullexception-using-net-tcp-binding   Eles falam sobre atualizar as bibliotecas para versão mais recente...

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Pesquisando sobre assunto, descobri que o problema estava na falta de instalação do pacote WebActivaotorEx, NinjectMVC5.

Answer (score 1):

[Conforme falado por comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157149/asp-net-web-api#comment324001_157149), verifique se o pacote [WebActivatorEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebActivatorEx/) foi instalado juntamente com o Ninject.

O erro:

> Cannot be null Nome do parâmetro: root

É disparado pelo Ninject, e não exatamente pelo ASP.NET Web API.